# Prestashop 1.7 get ajaxProcess variable in tpl file

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I use an ajax function below when submitting a button  ,the variable $ list_ref contains the correct result, how to assign this variable to use it in a tpl?
Any suggestion please

```
public function ajaxProcessSaveData(){


    if(isset(Tools::getValue("ref_product"))){


        $product_reference = Tools::getValue("ref_product");
        $id_product =  Tools::getValue('id_product');
        $product_name=  Tools::getValue('product_name');
        $img_product =  Tools::getValue('img_product');

       $list_ref = array($id_product, $product_name, $img_product);

       //var_dump( $list_ref);
      $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
             'list_refs' =>  $list_ref, 
      ));

      $this->context->smarty->assign('list_refs',  $list_ref);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`die($this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'modulename/views/templates/hook/abc.tpl'));`